# Qt serial port library

Tags: qt, qt4, serial-port

I want to make an app using Qt that communicates with serial port.

The problem is that I cant find a library that works and does this thing.
I need a non General Public License library I think.

Actually I am not sure cause I don't know if I can use a General Public License library for a closed source program.

I found qextserialport but I am unable to build it using Qt 4.7.3. I added all the needed headers but it fails on some functions.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: qextserialport should work. What build error are you getting?

Comment: :-1: error: cannot find -lqextserialportd

Comment: Is the library (i.e. `libqextserialportd.a`) in your search path? http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_21.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go closed source and distribute your application, you can't use GPL. You can use LGPL when linking either dynamically or statically. For the latter, [you need to provide object files for all of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18704890/1329652), so that they can be statically re-linked with Qt.

Conercerning your base issue, Qt 5 includes a serial port module. On Qt 4, you'll need a platform-specific solution. Reducing the scope might help to point you to something. I suggest that if you don't target portability, you should add relevant tags and comments. Otherwise, saying that you need a portable solution is a good thing too.

As far as I know, on most paltforms, accessing to serial port requires higher privileges, so be ready for that in your deployment.

Concerning [qtextserialport](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/), license is BSD so it would work for your clsoed source application. If you post a compilation issue on where it fails, maybe people will be able to help you

I tried to compile it using VC2010 and Qt 4.7.2 and head of project (I just cloned it) compiles flawlessly: I got a nice qextserialport1.dll (that I admit I didn't try using).

Comment: Well this "1" in the end of qextserialport1.dll made me to try appending it in my .pro file. It works!

Answer (score 3):

There is a QtSerialPort add-on nowadays that can be used for such tasks. I am one of the maintainers behind it. That is the "official" Qt add-on nowadays, so I would suggest switching to it. It will also support Qt 4.

It is properly useful for commercial code (closed source) as I have also been doing that. If we do not yet have an exception for static linking, I would even accept that if legally possible.

My opinion about licenses is somewhere in-between LGPLv2 and MIT, i.e. LGPLv2 + static linking.

Here you can find my blog post about it. It also works fine with Qt 4 as we have had put some effort into that support, too.

http://lpapp.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/qtserialport-in-qt-51.html