# C++ Qt making standalone executable file

Tags: c++, qt, static, compilation, executable

I have completed my code in Qt creator and it builds perfectly. now i want to pass on this program to a friend. but i cant even run this exe file myself.
i searched the web for this and i found that i would have to make my Qt 5.0.2 static.
i tried to follow the tutorials as to do that but i get stuck everytime.

i made the required changes to the qmake config file, but when i run the command prompt and the "configure" command it says "configure" is not a recognized internal or external command.

Comment: Can you see from where what you missed? http://www.formortals.com/how-to-statically-link-qt-4/

Comment: BTW, you can link statically a program you redistribute against Qt only if you either release the sources under the GPL license or buy a commercial Qt license. Otherwise, you are stuck with LGPL and redistribution of Qt in dll form (actually it's a bit more complicated than that, but in practice it's almost true).

Comment: @MatteoItalia That is simply false - not "almost true". *Any* linking of closed source code with LGPL libraries requires that recipients of the software need to be able to re-link the closed source code with such libraries. Such re-linking is done every time on application startup when you use dynamic libraries. With static libraries, you need to provide scripts and libraries needed to relink the closed source code with LGPL code. This *does not need to imply source code disclosure*. IANAL.

Comment: @KubaOber: that's exactly what I'm saying... the "it's a bit more complicated" part is the second option you said, that I've never seen in widespread usage since usually it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Since the entirety of the "effort" is to split the project into a static library subproject and an executable subproject, a task that should take a couple of minutes at most, I really fail to see the problem. There's a [simple workaround needed for visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704889/linker-doesnt-use-a-default-runtime-library-when-linking-together-libraries-onl), that's all.